# Some weird BTC transaction just happened to my wallet, sub wallet doesn't send back the BTC to my wallet

Tags: transactions, bitcoind, utxo, accounting, listunspent

So my wallet address is `3BA1kdxSyFLADWJHDeaFb2xap4QASVvXto`

1. First I sent 0.00010000BTC to `1FjpQCZvqQxpGjvdU8AcxVyxXgJqY17Uzw` (https://btc.com/e408f1e2126e4a504779e3be529b7b90e27e88a7547844743bf59401b8f77787)

My first question, why did my wallet also send 0.0998914 BTC to `3FT1hD7tHm9WRoMfBFSKoY9H2AXWAN7oDE`? who is this wallet belongs to? It seems that my node automatically created this address? How can this happen?

2. A month later I sent 0.00079509BTC to the same address `1FjpQCZvqQxpGjvdU8AcxVyxXgJqY17Uzw`. But instead of sending this BTC from my address it is sent from `3FT1hD7tHm9WRoMfBFSKoY9H2AXWAN7oDE`?
   How did this happen?
3. And on the next day, I imported my wallet to a different node. But I realized that 0.09989140BTC of my funds are not in my wallet but inside another wallet `3QNSBznq4mEJFxiSyshTWa7KuQRwYZ8hyA` that was suddenly appeared on this transaction `https://btc.com/22b3c9f8caa93f5f6968edc6ae93c13ca49063bf015c4b61ac8532b90cfa298d`
4. So I got panicked, but luckily I still have the back up of my old nodes and did `listunspent` on that node. and I'm glad to see that I have access to the wallet that hold `0.09989140BTC` (3QNSBznq4mEJFxiSyshTWa7KuQRwYZ8hyA) How did my BTC got stuck in there.

Is this a bug in bitcoin core (since I'm hosting the node on bitcoind)? or it is meant to be like this?

I am really worried now, what if I did not have the backup of my old node. Will I not have access to the wallet that hold my remaining funds in `3QNSBznq4mEJFxiSyshTWa7KuQRwYZ8hyA`?

How can I put back the funds in `3QNSBznq4mEJFxiSyshTWa7KuQRwYZ8hyA` to my wallet `3BA1kdxSyFLADWJHDeaFb2xap4QASVvXto`. Is there anything I can do with the output of `listunspent`? What is the meaning of the output in `listunspent` anyway?

Comment: This is completely normal behavior. The wallet follows the best practice of not reusing the same address again, but internally creates new addresses to send "change" back to, simply because it has to send that change *somewhere* due to protocol requirements. This helps privacy, as it is not (necessarily) clear to the network which output is the payment and which is yours. Don't worry, the funds are still yours, your wallet has all the relevant private keys.

Comment: @PieterWuille sorry if I'm have continuing on the argument, so the wallet bitcoin for all transactions generated a new wallet? and on this new wallet can apply a Bech algorithm? an example I have created new transaction whit an x account and to an x id wallet I apply the P2SH and create a y id for payment, now in the next transaction I have a new wallet with a j id wallet and a z P2H2 (supposed to use P2SH)

Comment: An address is not a wallet. A wallet consists of many keys and corresponding addresses. This has nothing to do with P2SH or so; outputs in Bitcoin have to be spent completely, so if there is too much in an existing output to send, another output back to the sender's wallet has to be created. This is simply wallet behavior; the protocol does not know or care which output is change or not, so any type of address the wallet can generate can function as change address.